# Solving optimization with exponential constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem as 
$$\min_x c(x)$$
$$ s.t. \quad \sum_i^n \alpha_ie^{-||x-y_i||^2/2l^2} \leq \beta$$

Here, $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is variable while $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n,\beta, l $ and $y \in  \mathbb{R}^m$ are constants.

The obvious straightforward approach is to use nonlinear solver like `fmincon`. But I want to know is there any way to simplify this constraint to decrease its complexity.

Also, I understand that the problem is non-convex. But not being able to show how?

Is there any source talking about optimization problem of this kind?

Comment: It is non-convex because even in the simplest case $n=1$ you are looking at the epigraph of a non-convex function $\exp(-|x|^2)$.

Comment: Are there any works regarding relaxation of such problems?

Comment: What is $c(x)$ ???

Comment: Can the $\alpha$'s be negative ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust c(x) is a quadratic function like $0.5||x-x_o||^2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes $\alpha$'s can be negative as well as positive.

Comment: If $x_0$ satisfies the constraint, the minimum is obviously $0$.

Comment: How distant/clustered are the $y_i$ compared to $l$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust $l$ has a very high value in comparison to $y_i$'s. Also, $x_o$ does not satisfy the constraint.

Comment: So you mean that the $y_i$ are well clustered. How far is $x_0$ from them ? Is the domain connected ?